# Hide custom fields on From:BAccount based on BAccount Type

Tags: acumatica

I'm sure this is a simple solution, but I am just learning a lot of this and also and not a developer.  Know enough to get lost.  Apologies for the newb question and thanks for the help ahead of time.

I am creating custom fields that are visible and editable on the BAccount form but don't want to show the fields in that column if the BAccount type isn't Customer.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Business Accounts` page CR303000. Use the `Inspect Element` feature in customization menu (top right) to find out the name of that screen graph (aka BLC/business logic controller) and the customer type field:

[image]

In Acumatica Customization Project Editor create a BusinessAccountMaint graph extension for that screen or use the shortcut from inspect element to create it:

[image]

In the graph extension you can put the logic to hide the custom fields when BAccount type is different than customer. By convention RowSelected is an appropriate event handler for those type of visibility validations:

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.CR
{
    public class BusinessAccountMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<BusinessAccountMaint>
    {
        public void BAccount_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            BAccount account = e.Row as BAccount;

            if (account != null)
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<BAccount.status>(sender, account, account.Type == BAccountType.CustomerType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consider following T100 training which is about making simple customizations: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t100-introduction-to-acumatica-framework/

Comment: For your specific use case you would replace "BAccount.status" with "BAccountExt.usrYourUserField"